# Simple random walk problem

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

We have state space $E = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and a Markov chain denoted by

$$(X_n)_{n\in \{0,1,2,\dotsc\}}$$

The transition probabilities are such that if we are in state $0$,

$$p_{01}=1$$

if we are in state $1,2,3,4$, we will go left and right with equal probability. If we are in state $5$ we stay there (with probability $1$, absorbing state). What is the first passage time to state $5$ if we start from state $0$ (i.e. what is the probably that the first time we visit state 5 is at time n)?

At first it looks like a simple random walk question to me but the tricky bit is that state $0$ goes to state $1$ with probability $1$ which sort of makes it asymmetric. Could anybody give their insight on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your $f$ notation is not as standard as you think it is, and so I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. Is it the mean first passage time? The PMF of the first passage time? The former is generally an easier problem than the latter.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that! I have edited the post and now hope it is clear that the f notation is a probability!

Comment: Well, you can set up equations: $f_{0,5}(n)=f_{1,5}(n-1),f_{5,5}(0)=1,f_{5,5}(k)=0$ for $k>0$, and finally $f_{i,5}(n)=\frac{f_{i-1,5}(n-1)+f_{i+1,5}(n-1)}{2}$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. Can these be solved?

Comment: yes I managed to solve it with both the recurrence relation you suggested and the method below, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $T = \inf\{n \geq 0 : X_n = 5\}$ be the first hitting time and consider the generating function

$$ F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n f_{05}(n).$$

Let us consider the process $\tilde{X}_n$ which is obtained by killing $(X_n)$ after its visit to the state $5$. Then its transition matrix $\tilde{P} = (\tilde{p}_{ij})$ satisfies

$$ \tilde{p}_{ij} = \begin{cases} p_{ij}, & i \neq 5 \\ 0, & i = 5 \end{cases}.$$

With this process, we can write

$$ f_{05}(n) = \Bbb{P}^{0}(T = n) = \Bbb{P}^{0}(\tilde{X}_n = 5) = [\tilde{P}^n]_{05}, $$

where the notation $[\cdot]_{ij}$ reads out the $(i,j)$-component of the the given matrix. Plugging this to $F(z)$, we have

$$ F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(z\tilde{P})^n]_{05} = [(\operatorname{id}-z\tilde{P})^{-1}]_{05}.$$

In our case, $\tilde{P}$ can be written as

$$ \tilde{P} = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

with $\tilde{P}_{ij}$ corresponding to the $(i+1, j+1)$-component of the right-hand side. Now it is not hard to compute that

$$ F(z) = [(\operatorname{id}-z\tilde{P})^{-1}]_{05} = \frac{z^5}{5z^4-20z^2+16}. $$

So it suffices to identify the series expansion of the right-hand side.

---

**Method 1.** Notice that $f_{05}(0) = \cdots = f_{05}(4) = 0$ and that

\begin{align*}
1
&= (5z^{-1} - 20z^{-3} + 16z^{-5})F(z) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [5f_{05}(n+1) - 20 f_{05}(n+3) + 16f_{05}(n+5)] z^n.
\end{align*}

So we may solve the recurrence relation

$$ 5f_{05}(n) - 20 f_{05}(n+2) + 16f_{05}(n+4) = \delta_{\{n = 1\}} $$

subject to the initial condition $f_{05}(0) = \cdots = f_{05}(4) = 0$.

**Method 2.** Expanding $F(z)$ amounts to finding the partial fraction decomposition of it. Brutal force will work of course, though this can be done more easily if we notice that

$$ F(z) = \frac{1}{T_5(1/z)}, $$

where $T_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the 1st kind. Therefore, with $\theta_k = \frac{2\pi k}{5} + \frac{\pi}{10}$ we have

$$ F(z)
= \sum_{k=0}^{4} \frac{1}{T_5'(\cos \theta_k)} \cdot \frac{z}{1 - z \cos \theta_k}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{4} \frac{1}{T_5'(\cos \theta_k)} \cos^{n-1} \theta_k \bigg) z^n. $$

Using the relation $T_n'(\cos\theta) = n \frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin \theta}$, this can be simplified further and we get

$$ f_{05}(n) = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{k=0}^{4} \sin\theta_k \cdot \cos^{n-1} \theta_k. $$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However the last entry in the transition matrix should be 1 instead of 0. And with that you would get f(z)=-z^5/((z - 1)*(5*z^4 - 20*z^2 + 16)),which when you differentiate,doesn't mean anything when z=1, which should've meant the expected number of steps to take to stage 5. Could you explain that? Thanks.

Comment: @J.Z., I am considering the killed process $(\tilde{X}_n)$. Why I am considering such process is that the corresponding transition matrix $\tilde{P}$ is directly related to the PMF of $T$. The relation is less clear if you use the transition matrix $P$ for the original process $(X_n)$. In fact, what you get is $$[P^n]_{05} = \Bbb{P}^{0}(X_n = 5) = \Bbb{P}^{0}(T \leq n)$$ because the state $5$ absorbs the chain and hence $(X_n)$ stays at $5$ forever. So if you use $P$ instead of $\tilde{P}$, then the corresponding power series becomes the generating function of the CDF of $T$ instead.

Comment: @J.Z. Now if you have $$G(z) = [(\operatorname{id} - zP)^{-1}]_{05}$$ instead, then still you can extract information on $T$ from $G(z)$. For instance, the expectation of $T$ can be computed as $$ \Bbb{E}^0[T]= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}^0(T > n) = \lim_{z\to 1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 - \Bbb{P}^0(T \leq n))z^n = \lim_{z\to 1} \left( \frac{1}{1-z} - G(z) \right). $$ You can check that this reduces to 25 in our case, which we can also confirm by other methods. Also, we have $$ F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\Bbb{P}^0(T \leq n) - \Bbb{P}^0(T \leq n-1))z^n = (1-z)G(z). $$

Comment: This makes so much sense now! I mixed up the two processes.. Thanks very much!